# Is this a UILabel Bug?

Tags: xcode, swift, uilabel

i have a simple custom View that have some UILabel as child:

```
class UINotificationDetail :UIView {
let title = UILabel()
let content = UILabel()
let date = UILabel()
let dismissButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
let kMargin : CGFloat = 10
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
}
convenience init(notification : UINotification){
    self.init(frame: RB.withScreen().make())
    self.backgroundColor = Config.grayColor
    self.dismissButton.frame.size = CGSizeMake(40, 40)
    self.dismissButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.dismissButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"x_orange"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.dismissButton.tintColor = Config.orangeColor


    let fontName = self.title.font.fontName
    self.title.numberOfLines = 0
    self.title.textColor = Config.orangeColor
    self.title.text = notification.title

    self.content.numberOfLines = 0
    self.content.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 12)
    self.content.text = notification.description

    self.date.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 10)
    self.date.numberOfLines = 0
    self.date.text = notification.date

    self.addSubview(self.date)
    self.addSubview(self.title)
    self.addSubview(self.content)
    if Config.isIphone{
        self.addSubview(self.dismissButton)
    }


}
required  init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override  func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
    let width = rect.size.width - 2*kMargin

    self.dismissButton.frame = RB.withParent(rect).sameAs(self.dismissButton.frame).right(kMargin).top(kMargin / 2).make()

    self.date.frame = RB.withParent(rect).sameAs(self.date.frame).top(3*kMargin).left(kMargin).make()
    self.date.sizeToFit()

    self.title.frame = RB.withParent(rect).sameAs(self.title.frame).bottomOf(self.date.frame, offset: kMargin / 2)
        .left(kMargin).width(width).make()
    self.title.sizeToFit()

    self.content.frame = RB.withParent(rect).sameAs(self.content.frame).bottomOf(self.title.frame, offset: kMargin / 2)
        .left(kMargin).width(width).make()
    self.content.sizeToFit()

}

}
```

That view is popoulaed from an UINotification got async from rest-service.
Everything work fine till i decide to create in the Administration one UINotification that had in the description string a word containing a simple : ì

If the cell and also the View detail have an UILabel with a text that contains di ì what i see is this in the cell:

[image]

And this in the details:

[image]

If the string doesn't contain an ì all is working fine:

cell:

[image]

Details:

[image]

Someone got the same issues? 
I run:
Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)
Swift 1.2
iOS SDK 8.3

Comment: What is the "issues"? I can't figure out what all those pictures what you even think the problem is. Please reduce the issue to a simple straightforward statement that anyone can reproduce for themselves.

Comment: Hi @matt, basically the problem i got is this: i have a custom view created programmatically. This view is composed via three UILabel. Without storyboard and auto layout i use the method "drawRect" called by View automatically when setNeedDisplay is called ( phone rotation ecc ) for drawing the view and put the right dimension of view frames . Everything is working fine till i put in one of the three labels a text that contains a ì. this char create a sort of bug ( you can see it in the picture i posted ).

Comment: "create a sort of bug" is not an explanation, and you still have not allowed me to reproduce the issue. You need to post code that _I_ can run. You need to say what outcome you expect and what outcome you are getting.